# Calling user control within a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have two usercontrols.

The first user control has a button and the second user control has a popup control.
I registered the second user control in the first user control with id=ctlPopUp

Onclick event of button I have to display the popup control.

I tried with

```
  protected void btnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var userCtlPopup = ctlPopUp.FindControl("pcDownload");
    userCtlPopup.Visible = true;
    }

It doesn't work. Can you please suggest?

Hi here is the user control markups:
POpupUsercontrol:
<div id="divDownload" runat="server" visible="true">
        <dx:aspxpopupcontrol id="pcDownload" runat="server" showpagescrollbarwhenmodal="true"
            clientinstancename="pcDownload" enableclientsideapi="true" modal="True" popuphorizontalalign="WindowCenter"
            popupverticalalign="WindowCenter" showheader="false" allowdragging="True" enableanimation="False"
            enableviewstate="False" width="600px" autoupdateposition="true" closeaction="CloseButton">
                        <ContentCollection>
                            <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl4" runat="server"
                                Width="100%">
                                <dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel3" runat="server">
                                    <PanelCollection>
                                        <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent4" runat="server">
                                            <div>
                                                <table class="cChildTable">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <h3>Download</h3>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="auto-style1">
                                                            <div class="hr">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDownLoadMessages" runat="server" CssClass="cMessageArea"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="cChildTable" border="0">
                                                    <tr><td style="font:bold" colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text="Content Link Title"></asp:Label></td></tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 30px; padding: 2px" rowspan="8">
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkImg" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: top" rowspan="3">
                                                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgUpload" Width="100px" Height="100px" Style="top: 0px;" AlternateText="No Image" />                       
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkName" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>                    
                                                    </tr> 
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCompany" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text="Company:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAddress" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                         <td rowspan="5" style="vertical-align:top"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddImg" runat="server"> </asp:LinkButton></td>              
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtyStateZip" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCtyStateZip" runat="server" Text="City, State Zip:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCtyStateZip" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPhone" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFax" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFax" runat="server" Text="Fax:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFax" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEmail" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email:" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOther" runat="server"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>                                                     
                                                        <td class="cLabel" style="width: 15%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblOther" runat="server" Text="Other:" Width="90px "></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="4">
                                                            <div class="buttons">
                                                                <span id="span2" class="cBtnLeft"><span class="cBtnMid"><span class="cBtnRight">
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDownLoad" runat="server" Width="65px" CssClass="cBtnRight" Text="Download"
                                                                       OnClick="btnDownLoad_Click"/>
                                                                </span></span></span><span id="span1" class="cBtnLeft"><span class="cBtnMid"><span
                                                                    class="cBtnRight">
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Width="65px" CssClass="cBtnRight" Text="Cancel"
                                                                        Visible="true" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                                                                </span></span></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                             </div>
                                            </dx:PanelContent>
                                        </PanelCollection>
                                    </dx:ASPxPanel>
                                </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                                </ContentCollection>
             </dx:aspxpopupcontrol>    
    </div>
Usercontrol where the popup user control is called
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlCategoryDetail" Width="100%">
    <dx:ASPxDataView ID="dvMARCCategoryDetail" runat="server" Width="100%"
        ClientInstanceName="dvMARCCategoryDetail" style="clear: both" ColumnCount="2" RowsPerPage="2" OnPageIndexChanged="dvMARCCategoryDetail_PageIndexChanged">       
        <itemtemplate>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table>  
                                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Image ID="ModelImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'>
                            </asp:Image>
                        </td>                      
                        <td>
                            <div style="width: 5px" class="Spacer">
                            </div>
                        </td>                       
                                    </tr>                     
                               </table> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                     <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocumentName") %>' Font-Bold="True"
                                >
                            </asp:Label></td>
                                </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:1em;">
                          <asp:Label ID ="txtText1" runat="server" Text="The May edition of News Brief contains seven newsworthy articles"></asp:Label>
                         </td>    
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td>
                          <asp:Label ID ="txtText2" runat="server" Text="Suggested Subject Line: The May 2014 News Brief has arrived!"></asp:Label>
                         </td>                                                       
                    </tr>
                   <tr> 
                       <td style="white-space:nowrap;">                          
                           <a id="clink2" style="width:60px">Content Link 1</a>   
                           <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" OnClick="btnArrow_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadArrow.png" ToolTip="Download Item" style="padding-top:8px"/>
                           <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/Add.png" ToolTip="Add Item" style="padding-top:8px"/>                         
                         </td>
                          <td> </td></tr>
                    </table>
                     </td>                                
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </itemtemplate>
        <paddings padding="0px" />
        <itemstyle height="50px">
        </itemstyle>
    </dx:ASPxDataView>
</asp:Panel>    
<div id="divCategoryPopup" runat="server">
    <downloadPopUp:categoryPopup id="ctlPopUp" runat="server"></downloadPopUp:categoryPopup>
</div>
```

On click of btnArrow_Click the popup user control should be displayed

Comment: We need more relevant code to diagnose this problem.

Comment: ctlPopUp.FindControl("pcDownload"); this would be giving null, you need to use like this ctlPopUp.FindControl("pcDownload") as ControlUsed;

Comment: Added the user control markups to the above questions. AM not getting the null value. can get the ID and other properties of the popup but it wont render the control

Comment: Are you sure it's not posting back? I think you want OnClientClick dont you?

Comment: Rex, Thank you :) was not getting ShowOnPageLoad in code behind. Now it works!